# How to get subdependency or version from dependency?

Tags: java, maven-3, guava, dependency-management

I have defined in `pom.xml` guava version for my project but in the common module I want use only subdependency of `guava`: `com.google.code.findbugs/artifactId:jsr305`. How can I get version of used `jsr305` or only subdependency `jsr305` same as in the guava?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of an elegant way to do this (like dynamically extracting the version etc), but...

if you just want to know the version (once) just look into the `pom.xml` of guava. With IntelliJ you can simply Ctrl-Click the dependency to open it, with Eclipse I think it's similar.
Then you can add this version to your main pom.xml in the dependencyManagement section, and in your commons `pom.xml`, you can just use the dependency without version.

In addition you can use the `maven-enforcer-plugin` to ensure that your whole project has no dependency conflicts. So if this would diverge at some point you'd see it immediately at build-time. See [Solving Dependency Conflicts in Maven](https://dzone.com/articles/solving-dependency-conflicts-in-maven). However, jsr305 is an annotation lib, so I wouldn't expect too many incompatible changes between versions (as long as you are using a newer one explicitly)

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <rules><dependencyConvergence/></rules>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

**EDIT:** in this case the version of jsr305 isn't defined in guava itself but in guava-parent